# Is there a program which can assign whole words as shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I would like to type entire words (using modifier keys) for every key on my keyboard. The desire is to increase typing speed by using less key presses.

For Example:

```
mod + A --> The
mod + Q --> Them
etc
```

Comment: Can you give an example input/output you expect?

Comment: @TuxForLife, exmples added as you requested.

Comment: @DKBose, They're not. I mapped the meta key to the start keys.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into

[autokey](http://www.maketecheasier.com/using-autokey-scripts-to-automate-linux-desktop/)

If it doesn't work out for you, you should consider using the keyword "macro" for future searches or asking a question